# C : How to optimise the memory consumption of the given c program?

Tags: c, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a c program which sends the data on every even index over MQTT and once the data is sent, the framed json is cleared and start constructing the new one and the process repeats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"
#include <jansson.h>

char *jsonString;


void sendMQTT(char *jsonString){
    
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;

    MQTTClient_create(&client, "tcp://localhost:1883", "client-pub",
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Inside MQTT :: %s\n", jsonString);
    pubmsg.payload = jsonString;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(jsonString);   
    pubmsg.qos = 1;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, "mqtt-ex", &pubmsg, &token);
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, 10000L);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

}


int main() {  
    json_t *root = json_object();
    char myNum[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 16, 32, 24};
    
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {   
        int json_size = json_object_size(root);
        if(i%2==0 && json_size !=0)
        {    
            jsonString = json_dumps(root, 0);
            sendMQTT(jsonString);
            json_object_clear(root);
            free(jsonString);
        }
        

    char key[8];
    snprintf(key, sizeof(key), "%d", myNum[i]);
    
    json_object_set_new( root, key, json_integer(i));      

  }  
}
```

When, I run this process over a period of 2 hrs approximately, the free memory gets alsmost exhausted and when I read the free memory after running continuously for 2 hrs, its ending up with 2 MB.

```
> show system cpu
Status='0,Success'
TotalMemory='62304256'
FreeMemory='3239936'
CPUUtilization='29'
```

Whereas before starting the above process, the free memory is 17 MB. How to optimise the memory consumption in the above given program?

Comment: This may seem like a nit, but `printf("..."); exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` is *wrong*.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Comment: `char *key= (char*)malloc(8);` you don't seem to ever `free` this memory again

Comment: Also the documentation for `json_dumps` states that you have to call `free` on the returned object when you don't need it anymore: https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.11/apiref.html#c.json_dumps

Comment: @UnholySheep I think that (your second comment) is the real problem. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @UnholySheep after adding the free for json_dumps, still I am facing the out of memory now this time memory gets exhausted for every 5 hrs approximately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`json_dumps`](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.11/apiref.html#c.json_dumps) states

> The return value must be freed by the caller using `free()`.

Since you never call `free(jsonString);` you are causing a memory leak, which would explain your memory issues (since you call `json_dumps` in a loop)

Comment: albeit freeing the json string, still facing the out of memory for approximately 5 hrs and so

Comment: the json dumps has been moved before sendMQTT function call and its working now.